# TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Tags: python

Есть код:

```
import pprint

def ImmediateNeighbors(Pattern):
    Neighborhood = [Pattern]
    Nucleotides = ['A', 'C', 'G', 'T']
    for i in range(len(Pattern)):
        symbol = Pattern[i]
        for x in Nucleotides:
            if x != symbol:
                pprint.pprint(Pattern[i+1:])
                Neighbor = Pattern[:i] + [x] + Pattern[i+1:]
                Neighborhood.append(Neighbor)
    return Neighborhood

def IterativeNeighbors(Pattern, d):
    Neighborhood = [Pattern]
    for j in range (d):
        for string in Neighborhood:
            Neighborhood.append(ImmediateNeighbors(string))
    return Neighborhood

print (IterativeNeighbors('ACG', 1))
```

На 11 строке `Neighbor = Pattern[:i] + [x] + Pattern[i+1:]` выпадает ошибка:

> can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Почему? И как поправить?

Если же `х` заключу в квадратные скобки, то выпадает ошибка:

> Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly

Comment: Что такое `Pattern`, что такое `x`, что такое `i`?

Comment: Думал, это не важно. Поправил.

Comment: Ошибка «Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly» на той же 11 строке выпадает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Neighbor = Pattern[:i] + [x] + Pattern[i+1:]
```

Pattern - это строка, а [x] - список. Их нельзя просто взять и сложить друг с другом.

Вообще не понятно, зачем вы оборачиваете x в список, это здесь совсем не нужно.

Уберите квадратные скобки вокруг x.

Вот здесь вы тоже что-то непонятное делаете:

```
Neighborhood = [Pattern]
    for j in range (d):
        for string in Neighborhood:
            Neighborhood.append(ImmediateNeighbors(string))
    return Neighborhood
```

Что вы хотели сделать этой конструкцией?

Вообще, просто опишите, какую задачу вы решали. Подозреваю, тут проще будет с нуля написать всё по уму, чем пытаться поправить то, что у вас получилось.

UPD: Оказалось, что у вас в 11 строке Pattern при некоторых проходах оказывается строкой, а при последующих - списком. Поэтому хоть заключайте x в квадратные скобки, хоть не заключайте - всё равно будет выкидывать ошибку, только на разных этапах выполнения...

В общем, как я уже сказал, приведите задачу, будем вам новый код писать. А этот просто пристрелите, чтобы он не мучался...